# while running a kubernetes application

Tags: docker, kubernetes

While running a kubernetes on local with docker with the following command

```
kubectl -s http://localhost:8080 run-container nginx --image=nginx --port=80
```

following error is generated

`Error from server: the server could not find the requested resource (post replicationControllers)`

Could someone give me some pointers on how to resolve the problem.
Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check docker service and apiserver is working correctly.

For apiserver: Use

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/
```

Output:
       `{
      "versions": [
          "v1"
          ]
       }`

And, use

```
kubectl -s http://localhost:8080 run-container nginx -image=nginx:latest --port=80
```

or

```
kubectl -s http://localhost:8080 run-container nginx --image=nginx --port=80 --api-version="v1"
```

Add your own api-version on the last flag